# how to differentiate between Singular and plural (to a reader) when using a second person pronoun to ask a question?

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns

**Are you Rich ?**

Could be asked to one person or a group of people.

is there a way to signal its singularity or plurality by itself.

a Solution For Ex: (  is you rich ? ) would definitely mean one , ( Are you rich ? ) would mean a group. **provided it was grammatically correct**

or

a completely different pronoun that represents different numbers ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did English ever have a "you" plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22194/did-english-ever-have-a-you-plural)

Answer (score 1):

There used to be: the distinction didn't last beyond Early Modern English (around Shakespeare's time).

> Art thou rich?
>   Are you rich?

*Thou* was the second person singular, and *you* was plural.

In modern standard English, there is no distinction and the number needs to be deduced from the context.

However, see also [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/354959) about dialects of English.

Comment: In modern standard English, you can say *all of you* to distinguish the plural *you*. And if you're just talking to one person, you use their name; "John, are you rich?"

Comment: You can say “each of you” also.

Comment: Both of those suggestions (and especially the use of a name) are providing the context necessary to interpret *you*.